# curl -d option with php for Sendgrid API

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid

I found this option in sendgrid mail platform for adding multiple email IDs to a list. It's like :

```
curl -d 'api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&list=my_list&data[]={"email":"address1@domain.com","name":"contactName1"}&data[]={"email":"address2@domain.com","name":"contactName2"}' https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json
```

Now how can I use this along with PHP curl ?

I am having doubt in adding the data fields and read somewhere that -d is the switch for POST.
But for sendgrid almost all the api requests are gets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

-d switch automaticaly uses POST method, so if your curl command works, you can use POST. And to set post data, you can do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_user=your_sendgrid_username&...');
```

or to have automatic urlencoding, use array

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('api_user' => 'your_sendgrid_username' ...));
```

Comment: Thanks bro. was looking everywhere for this answer.  :)